# Getting data from a backend server side file and displaying it on a client side html site

Tags: javascript, html, server, frontend, client-side

I have an AWS server that continually runs a program on the background updating a txt file. I want to make calculations with the latest file data and display it on an html page.

(I will also be using systemctl to host the html on the server)

---

I tried using fs but it's just not possible to access since it's a client side I think, I also tried searching for the situation I'm in but just can't find anything on it.

(Note: First time trying something like this and using a server so not sure what I can/can't do)

Comment: You can use `fetch()` to download the file into the client application.

Comment: Well, a server running something like php/python that can open and serve the file combined with the website running javascript websockets would be the best option. However, a backup option is using javascript and accessing the file via fetch on a timer would work too although not the best option

Comment: If you want to modify the data from the txt file and have it be written back to the txt file, then you will need something on the server to take that data and write it to the file.

Comment: Also, another thing to take into consideration is the update schedule of the txt file. If its constant like every few seconds web sockets would be the best option. If its something updated less regularly like daily etc.. then fetch would be the better option

Comment: @imvain2 The only one making modifications to the file is the program thats running on the background i just want to look, make a few calculations and display it to the client side.
Also it runs each 30m Should have written it better , edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) can help you, [fetch function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to be more specific

I suggest following solution

If this script works on your server you can make asynchronous function in javascript, that will fetch data from server once in a while and then using JS update table on frontend

Or, as It was suggested in comments - use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) with its [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)